# copy all copyQ tab names to a tab name tabs

Tags: linux, bash, copyq

i want to
copy all existing tab names inside [copyQ](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/) as items in a tab named **tabs**.

my prototype producing duplicates:

> ./tabs.sh ; copyq tab > tabs.sh ; sed -i 's/.*/copyq tab tabs add "&"/' tabs.sh ; ./tabs.sh

## i read:

https://copyq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html#working-with-tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the copyq removetab tabName removes the tab ( means also all items of the tab).

If the tab is empty at first, fewer duplicates are created.

`copyq show tabs; ./tabs.sh ; copyq tab > tabs.sh ; sed -i 's/.*/copyq tab tabs add "&"/' tabs.sh ; copyq removetab tabs; ./tabs.sh`

found by consolne command: `copyq --help`
and here: https://gist.github.com/hluk/95889230aeea2388dea5

works here in `CopyQ Clipboard Manager v4.1.0~focal`